# Ansible set_fact error when trying to set with conditons

Tags: ansible

I have following task

```
  - set_fact:
      node_type: >-
        {%- if "{{ node_plan }}" | regex_search('trial') -%}
        NT-plan_x_trial
        {%- elif "{{ node_plan }}" | regex_search('test') -%}
        NT-plan_x_test
        {%- else -%}
        NT-plan_{{ node_plan }}
        {%- endif -%}
```

it gives me an error saying 'node_type' is undefined

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'node_type' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/mccloud/ansible/linode_create.yml': line 36, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - set_fact:\n    ^ here\n"}

What is wrong?

Comment: ***but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem*** > you'll have to show more of that playbook if you want an answer. In what you are showing, you are never using `node_type`, so the error is not in what you are showing in your question.

Comment: You need to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

*This will probably not fix your current syntax problem (and might be seen as off-topic but can still help you IMO)*

---

Your expression if overly complicated. You can do the same job with a much simpler syntax respecting an ansible good practice: avoiding complicated jinja2 expressions in task definitions. See this example playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test_strings:
      - toto
      - test_me
      - trial_me
      - are_you_testing_me
      - you_need_a_trial
      - pipo

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "NT-plan_{{ item | regex_replace('.*(trial|test).*', 'x_\\1') }}"
      loop: "{{ test_strings }}"
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=toto) => {
    "msg": "NT-plan_toto"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=test_me) => {
    "msg": "NT-plan_x_test"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=trial_me) => {
    "msg": "NT-plan_x_trial"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=are_you_testing_me) => {
    "msg": "NT-plan_x_test"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=you_need_a_trial) => {
    "msg": "NT-plan_x_trial"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=pipo) => {
    "msg": "NT-plan_pipo"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Solved. 
The issue was in wrong comment indentation.
Never think it depends on it.